# java.lang.NullPointerException while using ServletContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I was examining the use of `ServletContext` when i got the null pointer exception. I don't understand why do i get this exception.

I have set the attribute in the `context` object from one class and then try to retrieve that from the second class using `getAttribute(...)`.

```
package ServletContext; // servlet1

import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("suhail");
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    servletContext.setAttribute("name", list);
  }
}
```

---

```
package ServletContext;  // servlet2

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
    LinkedList list2 = new LinkedList();
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    list2 = (LinkedList)context.getAttribute("name");
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    writer.println(list2.pop()); //**15th statement**
  }
}
```

Exception is :

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
ServletContext.servlet2.doGet(servlet2.java:15)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.11 logs.

Why am i getting this exception ? `list` should be initialized in servlet2

Comment: `servlet2.java:15`: Which line is that?

Comment: Are you sure you want to put the list in the servlet context? Not in the session or request for the current user?

Comment: @ Thilo the statement that tries to pop an item _(15th in servlet2)_

Comment: Are the servlets deployed as a part of the same web application?

Comment: @ Joachim Isaksson yes. Both are part of the same web-app and also the package !

Comment: And why are you initializing the list with a new LinkedList in servlet 2? This is useless.

Comment: And you have not redeployed the app or restarted the server between the call to servlet 1 and the call to servlet 2, have you? The servlet context is held in memory. It's not persistent.

Comment: @ JB Nizet indeed it is!

Comment: @ JB Nizet I was only trying to run `servlet2` and that got the exception. Now when i first ran the `servlet1` file and then ran `servelt2` i got the result. Can you explain this in an answer. _note:servlet1 is a blank file in a browser_

Comment: If you never execute the code which stores the list in the context, of course it won't be there (and will thus be null). How could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list2` is `null` there - you can't invoke methods on `null`. Perhaps you still haven't put the list in the servlet context? A null-check (`if (list != null)`) would fix the exception, but make sure you are properly putting the list in the context *before* you invoke the 2nd servlet.

Comment: I was directly running servlet2 without starting servlet1

Comment: well, if you don't run servlet1, it won't get to do its work, will it?